# python-gerrit-api alternative authentication

Tags: python, python-3.6, gerrit, python-gerrit-api

Is there a way not to hardcode the password in the python script while using [python-gerrit-api](https://pypi.org/project/python-gerrit-api/) module ?

```
from gerrit import GerritClient
gerrit = GerritClient(base_url="https://yourgerrit", username='******', password='xxxxx')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible solutions for this:

**Solution 1:**

Use the python `argparse` module to take the password as input from the CLI using the command-line arguments. Set the $GERRIT_PASSWORD environment variable, and use that in the password argument.

`./script.py --username=$GERRIT_USERNAME --password=$GERRIT_PASSWORD`

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--username', help='Username')
parser.add_argument('--password', help='Password')
args = parser.parse_args()

username = args.username
password = args.password

from gerrit import GerritClient
gerrit = GerritClient(base_url="https://yourgerrit", username=username, password=password)
```

**Note**: You can achieve a similar state by directly getting the value of the environment in your code, using `os.environ`, instead of using the `argparse` module. However, the recommended way would be to give the input using arguments.

**Solution 2:**

Use the python `getpass` module, to take the password as input from the user interactively:

```py
import getpass

username = input("Username: ")
password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Password: ")

from gerrit import GerritClient
gerrit = GerritClient(base_url="https://yourgerrit", username=username, password=password)
```

Both the solutions mentioned above are derived from the fact that accessing Gerrit over HTTPS either requires the password to be input in the CLI command or requires the user to enter it interactively.

```
(i)
git clone "https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$GERRIT_HOST/$PROJECT"

(ii)
git clone "https://$USERNAME@$GERRIT_HOST/$PROJECT"
Password for 'https://$USERNAME@$PROJECT': <Enter the password>
```